# javascript countdown timer new date from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        var newYear = new Date();
        newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1);
        $('#countdown').countdown({ until: newYear, format: 'DHMS', layout:
'<div id="timer">' + '<hr />'+
    '<div id="timer_days" class="timer_numbers">{dnn}</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_hours" class="timer_numbers">{hnn}</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_mins" class="timer_numbers">{mnn}</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_seconds" class="timer_numbers">{snn}</div>'+
'<div id="timer_labels">'+
    '<div id="timer_days_label" class="timer_labels">days</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_hours_label" class="timer_labels">hours</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_mins_label" class="timer_labels">mins</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_seconds_label" class="timer_labels">secs</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'
});
});
</script>
```

I am using this script to show a countdown timer on my web page...but instead of `newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1);` i want to get the new date from my database...how can i do that??

aspx code

`<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HF" />`
Code behind [The date is 10\21\2011]
    `

```
If defaultJob = False Then
                sql.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT OfferHeader, OfferDesc, MarketPrice, OfferPrice, Discount, PayInAdv, PayLater, ImageURL, AdTags,EndTime FROM " & offerTable & " WHERE CustID = '" & custID & "' AND BusiID=" & busiID & " AND OfferID=" & offerID
            Else
                sql.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT OfferHeader, OfferDesc, MarketPrice, OfferPrice, Discount, PayInAdv, PayLater, ImageURL, AdTags,EndTime FROM " & offerTable & " WHERE CustID = '" & custID & "' AND BusiID=" & busiID & " AND OfferID=" & offerID
            End If

        Try
            con.Open()
            sql.Fill(table)
            con.Close()

            With table.Rows(0)
                LblOfferHeader.Text = Convert.ToString(.Item(0))
                LblOfferDesc.Text = Convert.ToString(.Item(1))
                LblMarketPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(.Item(2))
                LblOfferPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(.Item(3))
                LblDiscount.Text = Convert.ToString(.Item(4))
                LblPayInAdv.Text = Convert.ToString(.Item(5))
                LblPayLater.Text = Convert.ToString(.Item(6))
                ImgOfferImage.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString(.Item(7))
                HF.Value = Convert.ToString(.Item(9))
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            sql.Dispose()
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try`
```

The date coming from database is 10\21\2011 but the timer shows 36 mins left ....why?? what am i doing wrong???

Answer (score 1):

Now modify your markup to have a hidden element

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hiddenDate" />
```

//Pseudo code

```
Page_Load()
{
    hiddenDate.value = datereadfromDatabase;

}
```

Now your script can look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        var newYear = $('#<%=hiddenDate.ClientID%>').val();
        $('#countdown').countdown({ until: newYear, format: 'DHMS', layout:
'<div id="timer">' + '<hr />'+
    '<div id="timer_days" class="timer_numbers">{dnn}</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_hours" class="timer_numbers">{hnn}</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_mins" class="timer_numbers">{mnn}</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_seconds" class="timer_numbers">{snn}</div>'+
'<div id="timer_labels">'+
    '<div id="timer_days_label" class="timer_labels">days</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_hours_label" class="timer_labels">hours</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_mins_label" class="timer_labels">mins</div>'+
    '<div id="timer_seconds_label" class="timer_labels">secs</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the value in an Hidden Field on page load and grab it using javascript

HTML

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdf_Date" />
```

Javascript

```
$('[id$=hdf_Date]').val() // Get Date
```

Code Behind

```
hdf_Date.Value = ValueFromDb;
```